# Using Float questions

Tags: python, list, floating-point, tuples

I would like to write a definition so that when I input a number, I would like to divide it up into different lists inside a tuple.

I can get it so that it works with an integer, but I can't seem to get the function to work when the number is a float instead.

So far I know:

```
First=[]
Second=[]
Third=[]

First.append([int(i) for i in str(number)][0])
Second.append([int(i) for i in str(number)][1:])
```

The Third tuple I would like any numbers that are after the decimal point to be in the Third=[].

```
def divide(numbers):
```

then at the end I know I would have
    print((First, Second, Third)

I am really bad a writing functions, so any help on how to form the function would be greatly appreciated. I am using Python.

EDIT:
I would like divide(123456) to have an output of ([1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [])
divide(123.456) to have an output of ([1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

The first number in the larger number will always go into it's own list, followed by another list with whatever is behind it (but before the decimal point), and then the last list I would like to have whatever is after the decimal point. There should always be three lists inside one tuple.

Comment: I have no idea what you want as output. Perhaps include a few examples with both int and float?

Comment: @ZoffDino I edited my question, thanks!

Comment: Do you need to handle negative numbers? What would the output look like in that case?

Comment: It would output the same as a positive. (it would drop the '-' sign)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `partition` to separate the number into integer and fractional parts. This will work even for numbers that don't have a decimal point. Then you can use your current code largely unchanged, and produce your third list in a manner similar to the second.

```
def divide(x):
    left, _, right = str(x).partition(".")
    first = [int(left[0])]
    second = [int(i) for i in left[1:]]
    third = [int(i) for i in right]
    return first, second, third

print divide(123456)
print divide(123.456)
```

Result:

```
([1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [])
([1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Note that this will only work for "nice" floats whose string representation is just a series of digits and an optional decimal point. For example, it won't work for `float("inf")` or `5e301`.

---

Edit: you can have some additional special casing for negative numbers and floats with no integer part.

```
def divide(x):
    if x < 0: 
        x = -x
    left, _, right = str(x).partition(".")
    first = [int(left[0])]
    second = [int(i) for i in left[1:]]
    third = [int(i) for i in right]
    if first == [0] and third:
        first = []
    return first, second, third
```

Comment: How come if i use an integer it will produce an empty list at the end, but when I type a float: like .235 it will output ([0], [0], [2, 3, 5])? Because I would like it to produce the empty list when there isn't an element that would go into the designated list.

Comment: Because the string representation of .235 does have a zero before the decimal point: "0.235". But it produces `([0], [], [2, 3, 5])` on my machine rather than `([0], [0], [2, 3, 5])`.

Comment: How would I get the function to print without the 0? Is there a way?

Comment: Not if you want `divide(0.235)` to return `([0], [], [2, 3, 5])` and you want `divide(.235)` to return `([], [], [2, 3, 5])`. From Python's point of view, .235 and 0.235 are exactly 100% identical.

Comment: I would like the 0.235 and .235 to output the same thing: ([], [], [2, 3, 5])